# Syntax Error When Creating A Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe with a Country column as well as year columns (spanning from 1960 - 2015). I wish to create a new Dataframe only containing the Country and the columns within the last ten years.

I have managed to get the last ten years into a Dataframe but not the Countries they correspond to.

```
df = df[['Country', '%d' % i for i in range(2006, 2016)]]
```

From the code above, I get returned a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` syntax in python needs to be wrapped either in parenthesis (creating a generator) or in brackets (creating a list). You need a list of columns in this case. So wrap the for loop in a pair of bracket to make it a list of columns and then concatenate it with `Country` with `+`:

```
df = df[['Country'] + ['%d' % i for i in range(2006, 2016)]]
```

Or as @DeepSpace commented, use `str` method to convert integer to string:

```
df = df[['Country'] + [str(i) for i in range(2006, 2016)]]
```

Comment: Yeah, but `'%d' % i` feels really unnecessary here. `str(i)` will be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestion.